# Android Youtube Api nullPointException

Tags: android, youtube-api, onclicklistener, android-youtube-api

i wroking android youtube api.i successfully created youtube api project and i can play youtube video when activity started.now i want to play video Only in button click.i have nullpointexception
this is a my code

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

static private final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "************";
static private final String VIDEO = "hjHnWz3EyHs";
private Button b1;
private YouTubePlayer player;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player.loadVideo(VIDEO, 36000); //error is in this line


        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
        YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Oh no! " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    //player.loadVideo(VIDEO, 36000);
}
```

}
what is a wrong? if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: remove that line in button click and remove the comment in `onInitializationSuccess` it will work. the instance vairable player is never initialized

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `player`. You have only declared `private YouTubePlayer player;`.

You can check the samples @

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `player` initialization at the `onInitializationSuccess` method, it should be as following:

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
    YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    MainActivity.this.player = player;
    //do other stuff like customizing player
}
```

Please also take a look at the samples folder [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.0.0.zip)

Comment: i added this (MainActivity.this.player = player;) but when i click button i have nullpointException

Comment: @user3345767 are you sure you don't have any init failure?

Comment: i can play video when app starting ,but i want to start video in button click only

Comment: @user3345767 `player` inside `onClick` method can be `null` because of 2 reasons: initialization failed; you are clicking before `onInitializationSuccess` execution

Comment: yes u are right.player is null inside onClick.how i can change my code in your option ?

Comment: @user3345767 well, as temporary solution you can wrap it into `if (player != null) {...} else {display Toast with error}` and keep looking why it's `null`

Comment: @user3345767 you try `youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, MainActivity.this);` in Button click. also change to  `final YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);` and play video in `onInitializationSuccess` by uncommenting the line